# how to parse html input value to json data at angular2 using typeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I am new to angularJS2.It might be a dummy question for you
I searched many forums and failed about getting input value to json value in typeScript. You know how I should write my submit() function to get input  values from screen and console it to screen when I click submit button? You can find the codes below. Please let me know if you have inquiries .

Regards

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
   <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
       <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="guiTransformatorStyles.css">
      </head>
    <body>
    <table>
     <br>
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <tr><td>   <input type="text" value="&nbsp;" ng-model="myForm.productName">                                                                                   </td></tr>
    </ul>
    </table>
   </body>
        </form>
     </html>
```

This is my typeScript file :

```
 import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Http } from '@angular/http';


 @Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'navigation.component.html',
   host: {'(window:keydown)' : 'hotkeys($event)'},

 })

export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

 form: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit(): void { }

 constructor(private router: Router) {

 }



 submit() {
   alert('submit');
 }


  }
```

Comment: ...`ng-model` and `ng-submit` are AngularJS syntax....

Comment: [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/QllfZvOlQ8hNhhrU1KMY/) Like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@AJT_82** said. You are using AngularJS syntax in a Angular 2 project. Use `[(ngModel)]` and `(submit)` instead of `ng-model` and `ng-submit`.

(Not to mention that you are starting a form in the `head` of your html and using `body` / `head` in a template)